# How many DOF does this system have?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, degrees-of-freedom

[image]

I saw the problem above and thought it would be fun to solve it using lagrangians. However, in order to do this, one has to know the DOF of the system. And this is where it gets confusing for me. Since we have been given a rolling without slipping condition, I thought that we only had one degree of freedom, namely our horizontal displacement $x$. But that seems a bit too few, since we cant determine the orientation of the cylinder from this, it feels like at least. So I invented two degrees of freedom, $x$ and $\theta$, where theta is the orientation of the cylinder. I then managed to solve the problem correctly according to my answer sheet, but I don't know whether my solution is correct.

When applying EL - equation to the lagrangian for $\theta$, I get an equation that directly correlates $\ddot{x}$ with $\ddot{\theta}$ on the form $-mR \ddot{x} + 3/2 m R^2 \ddot{\theta}=0$, this leads me to the suspicion that I might have too many DOF, but I'm not sure if that's a valid argument. So my question becomes, am I right to assume 2 DOF, and does it in some sense matter that EL applied to $\theta$ gives me the relation between the two generalized coordinates?

Comment: because the Lagrange is independent of  $~\theta~$ you obtain that $~\frac 32\,mR^2\dot\theta-m\,R\,\dot x=\text{constant}~$

Comment: @Eli I see that this gives us that angular momentum of the system is conserved. So it doesn't imply that I had too many DOF?

Comment: correct . the system has 2 generalized coordinate $~x~,\theta~$ 

\begin{align*}
&\left( m+1 \right) {\ddot x}-m\,R\ddot\theta +k\,x=0\\
&-m\,R{\ddot x}+\frac 32\,m\,{R}^{2}\ddot\theta=0 
\end{align*}

you can solve it for $~\ddot x~,\ddot\theta$

Comment: @Eli I think you missed 2m in the first equation. Thanks however!